# Передача типа класса в параметры метода

Tags: java, классы, методы

Как передать тип класса в метод и работать с ним ?
 Допустим имеются 2 класса Cat и Dog;

В классе Main я создаю экземпляры классов и использую метод Job.doStuff (здесь и далее псевдокод)

```
Cat cat = new Cat(2);
Dog dog = new Dog(5);
Job.doStuff(Dog, dog)   // тут поля заполняются вручную каждый раз
```

В классе, скажем, Job , у меня есть метод doStuff, который принимает какой-либо класс, создает пустой ArrayList типа переданного класса(Например Cat или Dog) :

```
Class Job { 
 doStuff( Class<?> , Object obj)
 { ArrayList<?> list = new....;
   list.add(obj);  } }
```

Собственно, как сделать так, чтобы метод doStuff понимал, какой класс в него передан, и, соответственно, как описать это в параметрах строки с комментарием ?

Comment: Ну и извращения. Почитайте про `instanceof` http://pro-java.ru/java-dlya-nachinayushhix/primenenie-operatora-instanceof-v-java/ и в  `Job.doStuff()` будет достаточно 1 аргумента. И вообще так не делается. Делается интерфейс `IAnimal` (`Cat` и `Dog` его имплементируют) и список создаётся именно с этим интерфейсом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте дженерики (generics):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.<Animal>doStuff(new Dog(), new Cat());
        job.<Dog>doStuff(new Dog(), new Dog());
    }
}


class Job {
    <T> void doStuff(T ... animals) {}

}

class Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{}

class Cat extends Animal{}
```

Ну или же определите метод следующим образом - `void doStuff(Class ... instances)` и гуглите всё про рефлексию в java.

Comment: Помоему еще так работает `Arrays.asList`. Только там не указывается тип до имени метода при вызове